# Assembly Language calculating recursive function

Tags: recursion, assembly, x86, procedure

I am trying to implement the below function on assembly as recursive function call.

```
Int  f(n) 
if (n<=3)   return n;
else        return  2 * f(n-1) + f(n-2);
```

When I ran the code, I receive 1 as a result.
Please advice

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.CODE
main PROC
    push 5
    call RECURSIVE          ; calculate the below function
    call WriteDec           
    call Crlf
    exit
main ENDP
;------------------------------
RECURSIVE PROC
; Calculates int f(n)
; if (n<=3) returns n
; else return 2*f(n-1)+f(n-2)
;------------------------------
push ebp                    
mov ebp,esp             
mov eax,[ebp+8]             ;get n
cmp eax,3                   ;n > 3 ?
ja L1                       ; yes, continue
mov eax,1                   ; no, return 1 
jmp L2                      ;return to the caller
L1:  dec eax
     push eax
     call RECURSIVE
ReturnFact:mov ebx,[ebp+8]  ;get n-1
           shl ebx,1        ;multiply by 2
           add ebx,[ebp+16] ;add n-2 and save 

L2: pop ebp                 ;return eax
    ret 4                   ;clear stack
RECURSIVE ENDP

END main
```

Comment: `[ebp+16]` is bad practice, even if it might work. You are trying to access a local variable of the caller. You are calculating using `ebx` but then discard the result, so you are getting back the `mov eax, 1` only.

Comment: How can i fix it? Is my logic implemented properly?

Comment: `ebp` is not `ebx`, also that's not popping any result. No, your logic is wrong. If you look at your pseudocode, you can see that you need to invoke `f()` **twice**. Store the return value from the first invocation in a local variable (which you will need to allocate from the stack) then perform the calculation using that local and the return value from the second invocation.

Comment: What's causing you problem? It's the exact same thing, just with `n-2`.

Comment: I add the followings  ** - dec eax  -  add ebx, eax - mov eax,ebx **  but this time, instead of function eax value f(n-2) only (n-2) value is added to the calculation.My question is, should i call the recursion one more time under the return fact? or where I need to get f(n-2) value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148358/discussion-between-mwater07-and-jester).

Answer (score 0):

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.CODE
main PROC
    mov ecx, 7
    push ecx
    call RECURSIVE      
    call WriteDec           
    call Crlf
    exit
main ENDP
;------------------------------
RECURSIVE PROC
; Calculates int f(n)
; if (n<=3) returns n
; else return 2*f(n-1)+f(n-2)
;------------------------------
push ebp                    
mov ebp,esp             
mov eax,[ebp+8]             ;get n
cmp eax,3                   ;n > 3 ?
ja L1                       ; yes, continue
mov eax,[ebp+8]             ; no, return 1 
jmp L2                      ;return to the caller
L1:  dec eax
     push eax
     call RECURSIVE

ReturnFact: shl eax,1
            push eax 
            mov eax, [ebp+8]
            sub eax, 2       
            push eax 
            call RECURSIVE 
            add eax, [ebp-4] 
L2: mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp                 ;return eax
    ret 4                   ;clear stack
RECURSIVE ENDP

END main
```